# using on clause of a left outer join with the LIKE keyword using a dynamic list

Tags: sql, join, sql-like

I have a column in a table that can have a string `CSV`, I want to run a query against all those values with a LIKE that is apart of a ON clause to a outer join.

```
DECLARE @to VARCHAR(max) = (SELECT value FROM dbo.table WHERE id = 'key');
DECLARE @t table ( value varchar(max) )
INSERT INTO @t SELECT item FROM fn_csv_splitstring ( @to , ',' )
```

After I have gotten all the CSV values, I now want to have each value in my temp table used as an expression on the LIKE keyword similar to the below select

```
 SELECT * FROM 
 dbo.table e 
 where e.value LIKE '%' + (SELECT value FROM [@t]) + '%'
```

The exact statement is used on a left outer join statement, the ON clause links two table row IDs
`e.id = t.id` and then there is an additional AND expression  `AND e.value LIKE 'col%'` At this point I need to be able to have all rows in my temp table as a bunch of `OR LIKE '%'` or something that acts as `LIKE '%' + (SELECT value FROM [@t]) + '%'`

I have tried the `IN` keyword, but `IN` seems to only work with exact matches and not the wild card.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use EXISTS to check whether e.value is like ANY t.value (wildcarded)

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.table e
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM @t t
    WHERE e.value LIKE '%' + t.value + '%')
```

Comment: exists does seem to work in the join on expression which is where I am actually using the query

Comment: I assume you actually mean "does" and not "does <not>". That's great! I see that you are new to StackOverflow. Here, we mark correct answers as accepted to help users find solutions. Thanks